# Replacing images with their alt text if mobile screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css

E.g. I have a logo that when the screen size gets below 480px the images hides and its alt text is shown as a replacement.

I was wondering if there is a simple pure CSS solution or will I need to use jQuery?

Comment: Unfortunately no, even with CSS generated content (which is the only way I could see this working with CSS) it can't work, as an `img` can't contain any content. This will definitely require JavaScript, if not necessarily the jQuery library.

Comment: What purpose will this serve?  If you're trying to save mobile users some bandwidth, this won't work.  The images will begin downloading before you can use JavaScript to remove them from the DOM.

Comment: Its for a purely aesthetic reason, I want to swap out a logo for small text...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you can really do with CSS is use your standard image replacement technique for your desired breakpoint.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/0r7hlsnt

```
<h1>Meow</h1>
```

```css
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/400/200) no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    text-indent: -100em;
  }
}
```

Any [image replacement](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageReplacement/) technique will do.

Comment: adding onto your comment that you can't use the after/before psuedo elements on images or form elemnts, i checked http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content and http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/generate.html  and nowhere can i find where this is accurate, and this would be useful to know!

Answer (score -1):

With the appropriate media queries, can you do:

```
img::after {
    content: attr('alt');
}
```

Still,

```
img {
    display: none;
}
```

might hide the after section too.

Comment: You can't use before/after pseudo elements on images (or form controls).

Comment: @cimmanon im curious now.  where does it say you can't? don't see the limitation at http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content

Comment: And I now see in the CSS2 spec, Section 12.1: "This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification." CSS 3 offers nothing further. They might add such behavior, but I wouldn't hold my breath.  Sorry.

Comment: You can't put anything _inside_ an <img> element.